# HTML end tags doesn't comes in snippet inside Vue templates

Tags: vue.js, intellisense, vscode-snippets, vetur

I am very new to Vue Js (Node Version v10.16.3) and (NPV version 6.9.0)[image]
and I couldn't figure out how to fix HTML snippet issue.

I installed Vetur 0.22.2 and VueCSCodeSnippets 1.8.0 but still when i type  closing/end tag doesn't come after. I need to type

```
 </div> or </h1> </form> everytime i use.
```

But if I type  then  comes after, or If i type  rest of the end tag comes auto.

```
<script>
export default {

}
 </script>
```

Comment: It is more about a plugin in VSCode. Can you update your question with info about the version of VSCode you use? And eventually with a screenshot of your other pluginsthat may interrupt your vue plugins?

Comment: Thanks, Asqan. I just edited my question. Hopefully, this will help.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're expecting to happen. But had you already checked the [Vetur setup guide](https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/setup.html#extensions)?

Answer (score 7):

I found the answer by watching one of youtube video.
If I start typing with "<" it doesn't work. 
I need to just type "div" or "h" etc.. without this symbol "<"

Comment: please tell me you have found a solution for this

Comment: Hi Fathy, the solution is don't start with "<" just type div or any other HTML element without 2<"

Comment: not working in some cases such as .vue files "template" tag not autocomplete unless i typed "<" first  although i have Vetur installed

Answer (score 5):

you need some plugin to do the stuff, here I'm sharing one but there are a lot of others as well.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag

[image]